# How to view label and submit id in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-autocomplete

I have a search field which use jquery autocomplete.In this textbox that drops down a list of employee names suggested by the autocomplete.But when my form is submitted I don't want the persons name sent along with form, I want the employee id sent with the form.How I can do that?

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: array
});
```

This is the script I used.And the array look like

```
  array= [{"a",1},{"b",2},{"c",3}.........]
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JSON object like this

```
array = [
     {label: "a", value: 1},
     {label: "b", value: 2}
]
```

Field label it the text that user will see and value - id. Also you can use other fileds, such as `category`, `desc`, `icon`

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple values in autocomplete text box, then you need to store it in array and pass it through server side

```
var ids = [];
$('#id').autocomplete({

select: function( event, ui ) {
 ids.push( ui.item.value );
});

});
```

ids array will contain all selected employee ids, similarly you will also had to delete this id from that array if user deselect the employee from autocomplete textbox

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/dHsVL/)**

JS code:

```
var data = {
    json: "{\"employee\":[{\"value\":\"A\",\"id\":\"1\"},{\"value\":\"B\",\"id\":\"2\"},{\"value\":\"C\",\"id\":\"3\"}]}"
}


$(function () { 

$('#submit').click(function(){
    alert('Employee name = '+$('#employee_name').val()+' Employee id = '+$('#employee_id').val());    
});   

    $.ajax({
        url:"/echo/json/",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var arr = data.employee;
            $("#employee_name").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: arr,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#employee_name").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#employee_id").val(ui.item.id);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<form>
    Employee name (Type like "A" or "B" or "C")<br>
    <input id="employee_name" name="employee_name">
    <br>
    Selected Employee id (hidden field):        
    <input type="text" id="employee_id" name="employee_id" readonly>
    <br>    
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="check_fields()">
```